move does not work on a window in Qt6/С++ on Ubuntu
move doesn’t work for me when I create a widget, I give it the position of the previous window (not the parent), but it still doesn’t want to accept the position I need in Qt on Ubuntu, even though everything works on Windows
code:
if(query.next()){ // проверка результата запроса
        QRect currentGeometry = this->geometry();
        QWidget *loggetInWindow = createAccountWindow(userType, currentGeometry);
        if(loggetInWindow){
            loggetInWindow->show();
            loggetInWindow->move(this->x(), this->y());
        }
    }
    else{
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Ошибка входа", "Неверный логин или пароль.");
    }

I tried swapping show and move (I don’t know exactly which is correct) and nothing changed
supplemented code, LoginWindow is the first, initial window that opens immediately when the program starts, loggetInWindow
this second window opens after clicking the button
    #include "ui_loginwindow.h"
    #include "registrationwindow.h"
    #include "loginwindow.h"
    #include "adminwindow.h"
    #include "clientwindow.h"
    #include "workerwindow.h"
    #include <QPropertyAnimation>
    #include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase> // для подключения к базе данных
    #include <QtSql/QSqlQuery> // для выполения запросов к базе данных
    #include <QMessageBox>

    LoginWindow::LoginWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::LoginWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

    QComboBox *comboBox = ui->comboBox;

    comboBox->addItem("Клиент");
    comboBox->addItem("Администратор");
    comboBox->addItem("Работник");
}

LoginWindow::~LoginWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void LoginWindow::on_pushButton_login_clicked() // кнопка вход
{
    QString userType = ui->comboBox->currentText();
    QString username = ui->lineEdit_username->text();
    QString password = ui->lineEdit_password->text();

    {
        QSqlDatabase db;
        if(QSqlDatabase::contains("loginConnection")){
            db = QSqlDatabase::database("loginConnection");
            if(!db.open()){
                qDebug() << "Failed open database LoginWindow\n";
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "loginConnection");
            db.setHostName("localhost");
            db.setUserName("zxctatar");
            db.setDatabaseName("zxctatar");
            if(!db.open()){
                qDebug() << "Failed open database LoginWindow\n";
                return;
            }
        }

        if(ui->lineEdit_username->text().length() == 0){
            QMessageBox::warning(this,"LoginWindow","Введите логин");
            return;
        }

        if(ui->lineEdit_password->text().length() == 0){
            QMessageBox::warning(this,"Пароль", "Введите пароль");
            return;
        }

        QSqlQuery query(db);
        if(userType == "Клиент"){
            query.prepare("SELECT * FROM Клиент WHERE Логин = :login AND Пароль = :password");
        }
        else if(userType == "Администратор"){
            query.prepare("SELECT * FROM Администратор WHERE StrComp(Логин, :login, 0) = 0 AND StrComp(Пароль, :password, 0) = 0");
        }
        else if(userType == "Работник"){
            query.prepare("SELECT * FROM Работник WHERE StrComp(Логин, :login, 0) = 0 AND StrComp(Пароль, :password, 0) = 0");
        }
        else{
            qDebug() << "Unknown user type\n";
            db.close();
            return;
        }
        query.bindValue(":login", username);
        query.bindValue(":password", password);

        if (!query.exec()){
            qDebug() << "Failed query\n";
            db.close();
            return;
        }

        if(query.next()){ // проверка результата запроса
            QRect currentGeometry = this->geometry();
            QWidget *loggetInWindow = createAccountWindow(userType, currentGeometry);
            if(loggetInWindow){
                loggetInWindow->show();
                loggetInWindow->move(this->x(), this->y());
            }
        }
        else{
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "Ошибка входа", "Неверный логин или пароль.");
        }

        db.close();
    }
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("loginConnection");
}

QWidget* LoginWindow::createAccountWindow(const QString& userType, const QRect& geometry){ // проверка какое окно создать
    QWidget *loggedInWindow = nullptr;

    if(userType == "Клиент"){
        loggedInWindow = new ClientWindow(ui->lineEdit_username->text());
        loggedInWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    }
    else if(userType == "Администратор"){
        loggedInWindow = new AdminWindow();
        loggedInWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    }
    else if(userType == "Работник"){
        loggedInWindow = new WorkerWindow(ui->lineEdit_username->text());
        loggedInWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    }

    if(loggedInWindow){
        loggedInWindow->setGeometry(geometry);
        loggedInWindow->setWindowOpacity(0.0);
        loggedInWindow->show();
    }

    return loggedInWindow;
}

void LoginWindow::on_pushButton_registration_clicked(){
    RegistrationWindow* regWindow = new RegistrationWindow(this);
    regWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

    regWindow->show();
    connect(regWindow, &RegistrationWindow::windowClosed, this, [=](){
        delete regWindow;
    });
}

minimal reproducible example
    #include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QScreen>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    QScreen *primaryScreen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    QRect availableGeometry = primaryScreen->availableGeometry();

    int x = (availableGeometry.width() - w.width()) / 2;
    int y = (availableGeometry.height() - w.height()) / 2;

    w.move(x,y);

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}


You need to be more specific. For example exactly what is it about move that doesn't work for you.

I have an initial window, after clicking the button, a new window should be created that is not a child of the first window and appear in the same place on the screen where the first window is located
loggetInWindow->move(this->x(), this->y());

We need a [mcve]

Is loggetInWindow the newly created window? Which window is this? We need to see some actual code.

It looks like there is a lot of unnecessary code in your [mre]. For example, why do you need a QSqlDatabase to demonstrate one window on top of the other?

my minimal example is below the complete code

What is MainWindow? Apart from that, works on my Ubuntu.

Please replace the "linux" tag with the actual windowing system (probably Wayland or X11) that you're using. If the code works on Windows, it could be a lack of Qt on other systems, which may also be documented.

@zxctatar "my minimal example is below the complete code" -- The complete code should not be in the question. If more than your [mre] is needed in the question, then it is not a reproducible example. (If you copy the last code block as-is and try to compile it, does it compile? Or does the compiler complain that "mainwindow.h" does not exist?)
